# Getting MAC address issue Linux(Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have got MAC address as under.

```
struct ifreq ifr;
struct ifreq *IFR;
struct ifconf ifc;
char buf[1024];
int s, i;
int ok = 0;
string macAddr = "";

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (s==-1) {
    return;
}

ifc.ifc_len = sizeof(buf);
ifc.ifc_buf = buf;
ioctl(s, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifc);

IFR = ifc.ifc_req;
for (i = ifc.ifc_len / sizeof(struct ifreq); --i >= 0; IFR++) {

    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, IFR->ifr_name);
    if (ioctl(s, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr) == 0) {
        if (! (ifr.ifr_flags & IFF_LOOPBACK)) {
            if (ioctl(s, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr) == 0) {
                ok = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

close(s);

int p = sizeof(ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data);

cout<<"\n Size:"<<p<<"\n";

for(int i = 0; i < p; i++)
    macAddr += ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[i];

cout<<"\n MAC Address:"<<macAddr<<"\n";
```

I got `ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data` data proper, but when I print out I am not getting proper value. What can be the issue for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address in `sa_data` isn't in text form, it's the raw binary form, so you need to format it as hex yourself. You also can't use `sizeof` to get the size of the address as `sa_data` is a generically sized array - you need to look at the `sa_len` member to get the length of this address. In C you want something like this:

```
char *separator = "";

for (int i = 0; i < ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_len; i++)
{
  printf("%s%02x", separator, ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[i]);
  separator = ":";
}

printf("\n");
```